# Modelling negative prices

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

As recently oil prices were negative I was wondering if there was a possibility to model this behaviour by a certain distributional assumption of prices as the classical log normality is violated since prices can be below zero.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to 
https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Spot oil prices were not negative. The futures were. Look up what CBOE is doing in this regard. Also there's a lot of work on negative rates. The simplest thing is to assume normal instead of lognormal, shifted lognormal is another one